# Não consigo concatenar variável em uma query

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma URL e nela um código que vai variar o tempo todo (Ex: `usuario/perfil/39`).

Usei o seguinte código pra pegar esse valor da URL:

```
$valor_id =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$cod =  explode("/",$valor_id);
$codigo = $cod[4];
```

Então preciso usar esse código num SELECT. Fiz assim:

```
$sql = "SELECT tipo FROM users WHERE ID = " . $codigo;
```

E tive o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Error executing query: SELECT tipo FROM users WHERE ID =
>   - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\festas\registry\mysqldb.class.php
>   on line 243

Quando faço isso:

```
$sql ="SELECT tipo FROM users WHERE ID = 36";
```

Ele funciona certo, então acredito que o problema esteja em concatenar a variável na query.
Obs: no BD, o campo tipo é integer.

Parte do código que diz que ocorre o erro:

```
public function executeQuery( $queryStr )
{
    if( !$result = $this->connections[$this->activeConnection]->query( $queryStr ) )
    {
        trigger_error('Error executing query: ' . $queryStr .' - '.$this->connections[$this->activeConnection]->error, E_USER_ERROR); //LINHA 243
    }
    else
    {
        $this->last = $result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Qual o motivo de ter usado 4? Você quer mesmo o 5º ítem separado pelas barras? `[0]/[1]usuario/[2]perfil/[3]39`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voce pode verificar a saida do seu array desta forma:

```
var_dump($cod);
```

Isto deve lhe dar uma noção clara doque está sendo retornado pela URL.
Como a URL pode ser mudada pelo usuário recomendo testar sempre se o valor existe de fato.

```
$valor_id =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$cod =  explode("/",$valor_id);
$codigo = '-1';
if (count($cod) >= 3) {
  $codigo = end($cod); // Pega o ultimo valor do array
}
```

Recomendo tambem a limpar a variavel antes de utilizá-la na query:

```
$codigo = is_numeric($codigo) ? intval($codigo) : -1;
```

Por fim, experimente a utilização de [preparedStatements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). Alem de facilitar muito a vida, eles impedem uma série de problemas, como por exemplo SQL-Injection;

Answer (score 5):

Provavelmente seu código precisa apenas deste ajuste:

```
$codigo = $cod[3];
```

Motivo: se você tem um URL no formato

```
http://exemplo.com/usuario/perfil/39
```

a variável `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` conterá `/usuario/perfil/39`, portanto, após o `explode` você terá a seguinte estrutura:

```
0 => ''          (valor antes da 1a barra)
1 => 'usuario'   (valor entre a 1a barra e a 2a)
2 => 'perfil'    (valor entre a 2a barra e a 3a)
3 => '39'        (valor após a 3a barra)
```

Comment: Uma boa para evitar `0 => ''` seria usar um `trim`

Comment: @PapaCharlie nesse caso seria uma operação a mais, sem benefício, não?

Comment: Uso justamente para evitar a confusão de ter um índice vazio. No meu caso é mais por ser autônomo - minha router quem cuida disso, por isso limpo o índice zero.

Comment: Nesse caso o `trim` caso a url seja `/usuario/perfil/39`

Comment: O pulo do gato para saber qual o tamanho do array resultante é contar o número de ocorrências do explode na string mais 1. Exemplo: `explode('/', '/usuario/perfil/39/url/muito/grande//com/erros/')` - 10 `/` + 1. Array com 11 posições

Answer (score 3):

Confere se o valor de $cod[4] é realmente o valor que você precisa. Mas se o ID for o último valor da URL, faça da seguinte forma:

```
$valor_id =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$cod =  explode("/",$valor_id);
$codigo = array_pop($cod);
```

Answer (score 3):

Essa url certamente utiliza o Rewrite engine do Apache, então é mais fácil e confiável  fazer a edição do htaccess e fazer as coisas assim:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)$ page.php?usuario=$1&perfil=$2&id=$3
```

Depois no aquivo php é só pegar o `$_GET['id']`. Não vai ter erro.

Se não tem acesso ao htaccess e sabe que o id é sempre o ultimo elemento da url

```
$valor_id =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$cod =  explode("/",$valor_id);

$ultimo = count($cod) - 1;

$codigo = $cod[$ultimo];

$limit = array("options" => array("min_range" => 1));

$id = (!empty($codigo)) ? filter_var($codigo, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $limit) : FALSE

if($id)
{
   //executa pesquisa
}
else
{
   echo "ERRO";
}
```

Comment: Sua regra está errada. Criar segmentos não vai funcionar com `((.*)+)`.

Comment: @PapaCharlie, poderia explicar melhor porque está errado. Assim fica um pouco superficial.

Comment: Para segmentar no HTACCESS e criar varios formatos, é melhor criar um conjunto `([a-zA-Z]+)...`. Quando usa `((.*)+)` não permite dividir, pois ele vai considerar a `/` como caractere. Terá o `GET["usuario"] = usuario/perfil/39`.

Comment: Tem razão @PapaCharlie. Correção feita. Valeu.